# Export Data from SAP HANA Modelling-Views

Tags: export, hana

How to Export data from SAP HANA Modelling-Views?

I can export data from tables via

1. Right-click on table
2. Export
3. ... continue with dialog ..

But how to export content of an information view (e.g. a calculation view)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EXPORT() SQL command or the File -> Export -> SAP HANA -> Catalog Objects to export any activated information model.

However, this functionality may work differently from what you expect.
It does **not** run a default query against every object included in the export and stores the current result in the export. 
Instead, exporting activated views leads to the export of all objects the view depends on, including **all** the data in the respective base tables. On top, the DDL for the activated object gets exported. 
So, basically with the export of an information view, one can recreate the fully working activated information view on a different system.

This feature is meant for troubleshooting/testing/development activities - not for view result storage.